# How to avoid multi-byte file path bug of node-canvas's loadImage?

Tags: node.js, canvas, node-canvas

node-canvas (2.7.0) has bug which cannot load image from the path includes multi-bytes characters.

```
const { loadImage } = require('canvas');

const image = await loadImage('/Users/ユーザ名/Documents/test.png');
```

Such case causes "File not found" error.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should wait official bug fix, but following works as work-around:

```
const { Image } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs');

const image = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
  fs.readFile('/Users/ユーザ名/Documents/test.png', (err, buf) => {
    if (err) rej(err);
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => { res(img) };
    img.onerror = (err) => { rej(err) };
    img.src = buf;
  });
});
```